# unable to start Tomcat 7 server error org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

My tomcat server is failed to start despite of making sure everything is fine with installation.Can anyone guide me in resolving this problem.

[image: screenshot of error while starting the server]

Thanks

Comment: I can't  see the screen shot could you post the error message ?!

Comment: Included image of stacktrace, please next time post text instead of image

Comment: Please post the version of Tomcat and JDK that you're running it with, also it would be helpful if you can post the JAVA_OPTs value printed in the beginning by Tomcat.

Comment: Tomcat v7.0 server at localhost[Apache Tomcat] c:\ProgramFiles(x86)\java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: You should insert the stacktrace *as text*. **Never** use an image for text, it is not searchable, properly resizable, copy-pastable or in any other way but by manually transcribing it usable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `server.xml` comment or remove the following line:

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
```

Also, check if the variable `JAVA_HOME` is set and pointing to your correct Java installation.

Comment: Hi thanks, It works fine after commenting that.

Comment: Great, you're welcome.

Comment: In Tomcat 6, the Server Lifecycle Listener initializes the MBeans that may be used to manage Tomcat via JMX. In Tomcat 7, it's not used.

Comment: @deep so the only thing left to do is copy the error message as _text_ into your question to enable others finding it in the search

Comment: @marged error message updated now.

Comment: I can't see it, there is only a screenshot. Please provide  the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

It seems you dont have a server.xml on your project or maybe there a mistake on it. Can you check ? Or post the server.xml file ?

Sincerely